# VFP 9 FrontEnd Application with Oracle 10g Express BackEnd

Tags: sql, oracle, odbc, dbf, visual-foxpro

I have a VFP 9 application that make invoices, it works fine with its default database(.DBC) I am trying to port the front end of the application (EXE) to be used with Oracle 10g Express as back-end through ODBC or any other suitable method. I do have the complete project source-code.

The application has two style forms single record editing forms, and master detail forms these forms just adds/edit/delete Search.

This application was not developed by me. I am required to keep it as it is. I do keep regular backups but its database files (.DBF) get corrupted after any OS / Power failure. So i am thinking to transport all the data to oracle database and want it to be edited / added with existing VFP EXE with data in oracle. and get rid of DBF crashes.

my problem in this scenario is:
1) I can connect to DB with ODBC. have all data from DBFs to Oracle Database but have problem with view/edit/issues it won't work as normal.
2) I am not able to use VFP Wizard to generate Data Entry form with ORACLE REMOTE VIEW. that can view / add/ edit data
3) Can not find any way to change database Source in VFP database designer to replace tables with oracle remote views VIA ODBC.

Thank you in advance. any help suggestion or guideline is welcome and much appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the application was designed to deal with a remote data source, rewriting it to talk to Oracle is probably a large job. Before you do that, have you considered simply adding uninterruptible power supplies (UPS) to each computer involved. Data corruption in VFP is generally due to interruption; providing a way for users to shut down properly when power fails may solve your problems.

Comment: **Thank you!**   I agree with your point.  
after this many days i have finally decided to deploy oracle XE for remote sites. and using laptop instead of Desktop. and migrated all the data to oracle